# How do I make a mongodb replica set node "startup" after the server restarts?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I have 3 servers running a MongoDB replica set.
I currently start the node like this after restarting a server:

```
mongod --replSet "name_of_replicaset" --bind_ip localhost,this_server_hostname_in_host_file --fork --syslog --auth --keyFile "path_to_file"
```

The problem is that I have to do this every single time I restart a server.
I've checked online and the official documentation for MongoDB but I cannot find a way to make the server startup the node by itself.

Is there a way to have the server startup the node after it restarting?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using systemctl.

Create a service for this and enable the same via systemctl enable command. It will automatically start once you restart the server.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I will research systemctl and get it done. Thank you so much!